# Error: Can't get band number 0. Image has no bands. (Error code: 3)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api, google-colab

I am trying to download data from GEE python API using a shapefile but I am getting this error. Can someone please tell me what is the problem here?

**Code:**

```
country = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/username/assets/Canada")
filtered_data = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")\
        .select('B4', 'B3', 'B2')\
        .filterDate('2012','2013')\
        .filterBounds(country)\
        .median()\
        .clip(country)

task = ee.batch.Export.image.toDrive(**{
'image': filtered_data,
'description': 'DownloadingLandsat',
'folder': 'Example',
'scale':30,
'maxPixels':1e13,
'region': country.geometry()
})

task.start()
```

**Error:**

> Error: Can't get band number 0. Image has no bands. (Error code: 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incorrectly filtering the dates - the full date is required:

```
.filterDate('2012-01-01','2013-01-01')
```

You can debug such things by printing intermediate results.

```
print(filtered_data.getInfo())
```

This returns an image without bands. Why? Print more intermediate results. Finally you'll notice that you end up with an empty image collection because of `filterDate()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change bands names from `'B1'` to '`SR_B1'`, `'B2'` to `'SR_B2'`, `'B3'` to `'SR_B3'`!